# Why does it compile successfully when I pass only one parameter to a curried function?

Tags: scala

Why does line 8 compile successfully while line 15 doesn't compile? What's the difference between these two lines of code?

```
package test

object TestCurrying {

  def multiply(x: Int)(y: Int): Int = x * y

  def invoke(f: Int => Int => Int): Int = {
    val f1 = f(1) //Compile success
    f1(2)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val res = invoke(multiply)

    val f1 = multiply(1)//Compile fail
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by tpolecat on gitter, thanks very much to him. The following is his great answer:

> There are a few things going on here. You can turn a method into a
>   function via η-expansion. The expression multiply _ will give you a
>   function value of type Int => Int => Int that delegates to the method.
>   In a context where such a function type is expected, the compiler will
>   do this for you. This is what is happening when you say
>   invoke(multiply). You can partially-apply a curried function just
>   fine, as you see in f(1). You cannot do this with a curried method
>   (unless in a context where such a type is expected); here you would
>   need to say multiply(1) _
>
> multiply(1) : (Int => Int) would work however, because the ascription
>   gives the compiler more information about the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question lies in the difference between a method and a function. It really does not have much to do with currying though.

Now `multiply` is a method. When we pass a method to another method (in this case `invoke`) it is automatically `lifted` to a function. This `lifting` is done through eta expansion.
A Scala method is a part of a class. It has a name, a signature some body. 
A function in Scala is a complete object. There are a series of traits in Scala to represent functions with various numbers of arguments: Function0, Function1, Function2, etc.
See more details [here](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html).

The method scala provides to convert or lift methods to functions is the `_` operator.

Say you have a method

```
 def testMethod(n:Int){
//insert code here
}
```

And you have a line

```
val testf = testMethod(4)
```

This line would imply `calling` the method `testMethod` .
However if i write ,

```
val testf = testMethod
```

This would mean i am not invoking or calling the method but assigning the method to the variable `testf`. This `assignment` operation implies we mean to treat the method as a `function` ie.  a whole,complete entity. The compiler would complain about the above line and suggest you to add a `_` to `testMethod`.

For this reason we need to write ,
  `val testf = testMethod_`
for the assignment to be successful and so the `method` is `lifted` into a function. 
It is for the same reason that in your piece of code ,

`val f1 = multiply(1)` does not work as the compiler sees that the result of `multiply(1)` is a method that you are trying to assign to a variable and hence asks you to add a `_` as explained in the above case.